# java/javafx issue with static methods & "enclosed classes"

Tags: java, javafx

I'm attempting to create a simple tic-tac-toe game, and so far so good, but i'm having issues manipulating variables in the way I want.

I have two classes, one is called Run and the other is DrawBoard. DrawBoard holds all the methods for creating the letters (X, O, the board itself) while Run holds a lot of the main method calls and click handlers.

My issue is that if I make the drawing methods  not static, I can't reference methods to modify board state variables in Run (the various getters and setters), but if I make them static, then I get an error when attempting to use methods from DrawBoard in Run, but for some reason, only ones that are encapsulated in the click handler (note that the Drawboard.DrawMainBoard works). The error says "Drawboard is not an enclosing class".

I'm somewhat new to Java, so this might not be the most efficient way of doing things, but here's my code.

```
public class Run extends Application
{
    Group root = new Group();
    Pane characters = new Pane();
    boolean isPlayerOneTurn = true;

    //Values representing state of a square
    int TL, TM, TR, ML, M, MR, BL, BM, BR;

    public void start (Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Scene mainScene = new Scene(root, 600, 600);

        DrawBoard.DrawMainBoard board = new DrawBoard.DrawMainBoard();

        clicky(mainScene);

        root.getChildren().addAll(board,characters);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Test Game");
        primaryStage.setScene(mainScene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    void clicky (Scene scene)
    {
        scene.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                if (!event.isControlDown())
                {
                    double mouseXPos = event.getSceneX();
                    double mouseYPos = event.getSceneY();

                    if(isPlayerOneTurn)
                    {
                        DrawBoard.drawX ex = new DrawBoard.drawX(mouseXPos, mouseYPos);
//The 2 method calls I was referring to

                        characters.getChildren().add(ex);
                        isPlayerOneTurn = false;
                   }
                    else
                    {
                        DrawBoard.drawO oh = new DrawBoard.drawO(mouseXPos, mouseYPos);
                        characters.getChildren().add(oh);
                        isPlayerOneTurn = true;
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }
 public int getTL()
    {
        return TL;
    }
    public int getTM()
    {
        return TM;
    }
    public int getTR()
    {
        return TR;
    }
    public int getML()
    {
        return ML;
    }
    public int getM()
    {
        return M;
    }
    public int getMR()
    {
        return MR;
    }
    public int getBL()
    {
        return BL;
    }
    public int getBM()
    {
        return BM;
    }
    public int getBR()
    {
        return BR;
    }

    public void setTL(int newTL)
    {
        TL = newTL;
    }
    public void setTM(int newTM)
    {
        TM = newTM;
    }
    public void setTR(int newTR)
    {
        TR = newTR;
    }
    public void setML(int newML)
    {
        ML = newML;
    }
    public void setM(int newM)
    {
        M = newM;
    }
    public void setMR(int newMR)
    {
        MR = newMR;
    }
    public void setBL(int newBL)
    {
        BL = newBL;
    }
    public void setBM(int newBM)
    {
        BM = newBM;
    }
    public void setBR(int newBR)
    {
        BR = newBR;
    }
}



public class DrawBoard extends Run
{

    public static class DrawMainBoard extends Pane
    {
        public DrawMainBoard()
        {
            Line v1 = new Line();
            Line v2 = new Line();
            Line h1 = new Line();
            Line h2 = new Line();

            v1.setStartX(200);
            v1.setStartY(0);
            v1.setEndX(200);
            v1.setEndY(600);

            v2.setStartX(400);
            v2.setStartY(0);
            v2.setEndX(400);
            v2.setEndY(600);

            h1.setStartX(0);
            h1.setStartY(200);
            h1.setEndX(600);
            h1.setEndY(200);

            h2.setStartX(0);
            h2.setStartY(400);
            h2.setEndX(600);
            h2.setEndY(400);

            getChildren().addAll(v1,v2,h1,h2);
        }
    }

    public class drawX extends Pane
    {
        public drawX(double mouseXPos, double mouseYPos)
        {
            Line x1 = new Line();
            Line x2 = new Line();
            //Top Left
            if(mouseXPos < 200 && mouseYPos < 200)
            {
                if(getTL() != 1 && getTL() != 2)
                {
                    x1.setStartX(50);
                    x1.setStartY(50);
                    x1.setEndX(150);
                    x1.setEndY(150);

                    x2.setStartX(150);
                    x2.setStartY(50);
                    x2.setEndX(50);
                    x2.setEndY(150);
                    setTL(1);
                }

            }
            //Top middle
            else if (mouseXPos > 200 && mouseXPos < 400 && mouseYPos < 200 )
            {
                if(getTM() != 1 && getTM() != 2)
                {
                    x1.setStartX(250);
                    x1.setStartY(50);
                    x1.setEndX(350);
                    x1.setEndY(150);

                    x2.setStartX(350);
                    x2.setStartY(50);
                    x2.setEndX(250);
                    x2.setEndY(150);
                    setTM(1);
                }
            }
            //Top right
            else if (mouseXPos > 400 && mouseYPos < 200)
            {
                if(getTR() != 1 && getTR() != 2)
                {
                    x1.setStartX(450);
                    x1.setStartY(50);
                    x1.setEndX(550);
                    x1.setEndY(150);

                    x2.setStartX(550);
                    x2.setStartY(50);
                    x2.setEndX(450);
                    x2.setEndY(150);
                    setTR(1);
                }
            }
            //Middle left
            else if (mouseXPos < 200 && mouseYPos > 200 && mouseYPos < 400)
            {
                x1.setStartX(50);
                x1.setStartY(250);
                x1.setEndX(150);
                x1.setEndY(350);

                x2.setStartX(150);
                x2.setStartY(250);
                x2.setEndX(50);
                x2.setEndY(350);
                setML(1);
            }
            //middle
            else if (mouseXPos > 200 && mouseXPos < 400 &mouseYPos > 200 && mouseYPos < 400)
            {
                x1.setStartX(250);
                x1.setStartY(250);
                x1.setEndX(350);
                x1.setEndY(350);

                x2.setStartX(350);
                x2.setStartY(250);
                x2.setEndX(250);
                x2.setEndY(350);
                setM(1);
            }
            //middle right
            else if (mouseXPos > 400 && mouseYPos > 200 && mouseYPos < 400)
            {
                x1.setStartX(450);
                x1.setStartY(250);
                x1.setEndX(550);
                x1.setEndY(350);

                x2.setStartX(550);
                x2.setStartY(250);
                x2.setEndX(450);
                x2.setEndY(350);
                setMR(1);
            }
            //bottom left
            else if (mouseXPos < 200 && mouseYPos > 400)
            {
                x1.setStartX(50);
                x1.setStartY(450);
                x1.setEndX(150);
                x1.setEndY(550);

                x2.setStartX(150);
                x2.setStartY(450);
                x2.setEndX(50);
                x2.setEndY(550);
                setBL(1);
            }
            //bottom middle
            else if (mouseXPos > 200 && mouseXPos < 400 && mouseYPos > 400)
            {
                x1.setStartX(250);
                x1.setStartY(450);
                x1.setEndX(350);
                x1.setEndY(550);

                x2.setStartX(350);
                x2.setStartY(450);
                x2.setEndX(250);
                x2.setEndY(550);
                setBM(1);
            }
            //bottom right
            else if(mouseXPos > 400 && mouseYPos > 400)
            {
                x1.setStartX(450);
                x1.setStartY(450);
                x1.setEndX(550);
                x1.setEndY(550);

                x2.setStartX(550);
                x2.setStartY(450);
                x2.setEndX(450);
                x2.setEndY(550);
                setBR(1);
            }
            getChildren().addAll(x1,x2);

        }
    }

    public class drawO extends Pane
    {

        public drawO (double mouseXPos, double mouseYPos)
        {
            Circle circle = new Circle(75);

            //Top Left
            if(mouseXPos < 200 && mouseYPos < 200)
            {
                circle.setCenterX(100);
                circle.setCenterY(100);
            }
            //Top middle
            else if (mouseXPos > 200 && mouseXPos < 400 && mouseYPos < 200 )
            {
                circle.setCenterX(300);
                circle.setCenterY(100);
            }
            //Top right
            else if (mouseXPos > 400 && mouseYPos < 200)
            {
                circle.setCenterX(500);
                circle.setCenterY(100);
            }
            //Middle left
            else if (mouseXPos < 200 && mouseYPos > 200 && mouseYPos < 400)
            {
                circle.setCenterX(100);
                circle.setCenterY(300);
            }
            //middle
            else if (mouseXPos > 200 && mouseXPos < 400 &mouseYPos > 200 && mouseYPos < 400)
            {
               circle.setCenterX(300);
                circle.setCenterY(300);
            }
            //middle right
            else if (mouseXPos > 400 && mouseYPos > 200 && mouseYPos < 400)
            {
                circle.setCenterX(500);
                circle.setCenterY(300);
            }
            //bottom left
            else if (mouseXPos < 200 && mouseYPos > 400)
            {
                circle.setCenterX(100);
                circle.setCenterY(500);
            }
            //bottom middle
            else if (mouseXPos > 200 && mouseXPos < 400 && mouseYPos > 400)
            {
               circle.setCenterX(300);
                circle.setCenterY(500);
            }
            //bottom right
            else if(mouseXPos > 400 && mouseYPos > 400)
            {
               circle.setCenterX(500);
                circle.setCenterY(500);
            }
            getChildren().addAll(circle);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are implementing inheritance wrong here. Usually you want to ensure an "is-a" relationship (ie. A tiger is a cat) for inheritance. In your case the first thing that pops out to me is: `Drawboard` is not a `Run`. This is a core concept of OOP that you **must** understand.

Answer (score 0):

Why `DrawBoard` shall extend Run? This makes no sense for me. Remove it.

Have also `DrawBoard board;` as member of `Run`.

You dont even need `DrawMainBoard` class, it shall be also a simple function of `DrawBoard`:

```
public Pane drawMainBoard()
{ ... your code here ... }
```

Another point because this class-nesting is really strange:

What's behind having such a class `public class drawO extends Pane`?

This method simply could be method of `DrawBoard`:

```
public Pane drawO(double mouseXPos, double mouseYPos)
```

Same is true for `drawX`.

This way: 
Run has the member `drawBoard`, you can add the main board as: `root.getChildren().addAll(drawBoard.drawMainBoard(),characters);` and you can draw X and O like `drawBoard.drawO(x,y);`

And for the comment of [A.Sharma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3386635/a-sharma): yes, you shall learn what is the [difference](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html) between [composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) and [inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inheritance_%28object-oriented_programming%29).